# X-Cart 404 Page not found

Tags: x-cart

I have one problem with my x-cart website. When I click on any menu or any featured product, it show the below message:

```
404
Page not found

The page you are trying to access does not exist on this server.
Possible reasons:

- The page may have been moved or deleted
- You may have used an outdated or broken link
- You may have typed the address (URL) incorrectly
```

Can you give me any idea about this error, because I don't do any change with this website.

My website: http://www.toyscenter.biz/

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your product categories in the store administration. It seems that your categories are missing.

Comment: Thanks @vasilis, I already checked it in the xcart back-end too but it did not show any categories (empty category). What should I do?

Comment: Do you mean that there are not any categories? If there are not any categories, then it is logical that the menu and the featured products output a 404 page not found, since these links lead to specific categories. For some reason, they have been deleted from the database. You will need to re-populate your store database with categories/products (restore from backup if available - ask your server host company, if you don't have one yourself).